# selenium driver, button=driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='alpha']") Message: no such element: Unable to locate element

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

i want to avoid the exception or error due to unfound button, and change a variable to stop the loop.
i couldn't find on documentation what it really return in case of unexistant element

```
while there_is_more:
    button=driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='alpha']")

    if not button :
        there_is_more=False
```

The goal is to stop when the button is not found

Comment: You can use `try...catch` blocks for that.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this, il solved my problem perfectly

```
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
    
    try:
        more_button=driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='alpha']")
        more_button.click()

    except NoSuchElementException:
        there_is_more= False
```

Answer (score 0):

```
while there_is_more:
    button=driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//input[@id='alpha']")

    if len(button)==0 :
        there_is_more=False
```

use find elements and check for the result list.